# How to do many different things at the same time in Racket?

Tags: functional-programming, racket

For example, how can I do three different things in the same 'else' branch in Racket?
Like

```
(if (equal? temp2 #f)
#f
temp2
(vector-set! cache counter temp2)
(set! counter (+ counter 1)))
)
```

Answer (score 3):

Put the expressions that need to be executed sequentially inside a `(begin ...)` block, or use a `cond` expression, which implicitly uses a begin block. Like this:

```
(if <condition>
    (begin ; consequent
      exp1
      exp2)
    (begin ; alternative 
      exp3
      exp4))
```

Or even simpler:

```
(cond (<condition>
       exp1 ; consequent
       exp2)
      (else
       exp3 ; alternative 
       exp4))
```